# Having problem with running my CSS on VS Code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I am new to using vscode. I am trying to practice HTML and CSS. I was able to run my HTML but when I try to debug and run my CSS its not working. it says file can't be reached. Thanks

Comment: Attach your code.

Comment: What do you mean by "run my CSS" ? Your are supposed to link your CSS file in your HTML code.

Comment: you can't debug HTML and css, you have to paste the file path in the browser to run it

Comment: That sounds like the path in the stylesheet `<link>` element is wrong, so probably a typo somewhere.

Comment: which tool do you use to **RUN** CSS

Answer (score 1):

You have to link your css file like this:

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
```

Comment: why don't you close the link tag

Comment: In HTML5, so-called void elements (elements that can't have content) don't need the closing tag as they are self-closing.

Comment: in HTML5 **NO** element is self closing, because HTML5 is XML and XML has no self closing tags, browsers should barf at this type of errors, but they don't because it would mean half the internet pages would not be rendered

Answer (score -1):

{You should post your code}

Remember to add this line in HTML

`<style href='Your CSS file name'></style>`

Or you can also use:

`<link href='Your CSS file name'></link>`

Comment: That isn't valid HTML and won't work.